# OpenCV image recognition app : very good results on desktop but not on android

Tags: android, python, opencv, kivy

I've built an image recognition app in Python with OpenCV and Kivy for the UI. Basically, the purpose of the app is to recognize a set of cards used in a board game and show an HD numeric version on the screen (with additional informations).

It uses ORB for feature detection and description and Flann for feature matching. Everything works exactly as I want on desktop (Ubuntu 14.10 and Windows 7 and 8) which means I have no false positives.

When I build the app for Android (using buildozer and the last version of Kivy) everything compiles well, and the app runs nicely. The problem is that the recognition seems completely messed up : I now only have false positives ! The code on android and on desktop is almost identical (I just check the database less often for performance purposes) and I use a Kivy Camera widget on both platforms to get the preview.

My guess is that it comes from the different camera providers used by Kivy on Android (camera_android.py) and on Ubuntu (camera_pygst.py) but maybe I am wrong.

Another lead would be to do some sort of camera calibration but I am not sure how to do that. Maybe by tweaking the android.hardware.Camera Parameters ?

Has someone any clue about why the app behaves so differently on both platforms ?

Comment: did you use some size-limits on the desktop version? For example minimum/maximum ORB detection `octaves` (not sure whether it is called octaves too for ORB)? Do the image resolutions differ on both platforms? Can you try to resize the android image to fit the desktop image resolution coarsely before performing your algorithms?

Comment: No, the image resolutions are the same, so no resize needed. I didn't use some size-limit on desktop. Do you think it could help ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when using opencv's videocapture method. My solution is to use the plyer module (https://github.com/kivy/plyer).   from plyer import camera    that will help to solve your problem.  BTY, would you like to share your code